# ActionBar text not visible

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I use a regular ActionBar in my Android project. In onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clientlogin);

    getActionBar().show();
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF4444")));
....
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_clientlogin, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

menu_clientlogin:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_offline_mode"
        android:name="@string/offline_mode"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Everything worked perfectly until I added a [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), I used the code from the example project. The ActionBar color is still red but all the items are invisible (There is not text shown). If I click at the right corner of the ActionBar I see that I select an item and onOptionsItemSelected is triggered correctly.

I have the same problem in all other activities of my project. Another example (The ActionBar color is changed programmaticly, the drawericon is also shown):

[image: Invisible ActionBar?!]

My application uses this theme:

```
<resources>
    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you please check whether your background color and the text color you are using is  not the same?

Comment: Before the NavigationDrawer the color was white, but if I select an item it's too small (it's just an empty TextView)